# How to account for a investment income on estimated tax?

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax

I had a short-term investment payoff $40k. This figure will appear on the K-1 which I will receive in August. Meanwhile, what's the easiest place to stick this figure somewhere while doing estimated taxes? Is it OK to simply add it to "Other Income".

Comment: @littleadv [Please read this meta post](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2110/10997).  OP is a new user whose location is in his or her user profile.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "doing estimated taxes"? Are you trying to calculate how much to send with 1040-ES?

Generally, short term investment income will be taxed at ordinary marginal rates, so yes - "other income" sounds reasonable (depending on what it means for you, of course). Keep in mind potential NIIT and extra Medicare that you may need to pay, depending on your total income.